# Adding multiple numbers of parameters to a python function with a forloop in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, sympy

I am very new to the sympy package
I have created a funtion to show a graph of a elipse....
here is the code bellow:

```
import sympy as sp
x,y,z = sp.symbols("x,y,z")
eq = sp.Eq((x**2/4)+(y**2/9),1)
solve = sp.solve(eq,y)
sp.plot(solve[0],solve[1])
```

now what I want is that the list line should be done with a forloop....where there should be solve[i] as many times as the length of the list solve itself...

```
sp.plot(solve[0],solve[1])
```

Is it Possible? if yes then how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us `solve`

Answer (score 1):

In this case I don't think you need a for loop. You can just unpack the elements of your `solve` variable into the `plot` command:

```
sp.plot(*solve)
```